# how to register user in STRIPE through STRIPE API in PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using **STRIPE** payment gateway for a PHP application. While creating users in this system, I need to create their **STRIPE** account as well, is it possible through **STRIPE API**?

**Process would be as follows -**

```
1. User will register in our application and will fill up all the required details
2. Once the personal details are filled up, user needs to pay for the registration through STRIPE.
3. If user doesn't have STRIPE account then he/she would be redirected to the STRIPE payment gateway page registration page, where all the required details will be automatically filled up in that registration form.
4. User will submit that form and would be registered.
5 Once the registration is done, he /she will pay the required amount and would be back to the website.
```

Please let me know if the above mentioned could be achieved or not.

Thanks in advance.

Mohit

Answer (score 3):

If your platform uses [managed accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts), then you should create accounts via the API, as [explained in the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts#creating-a-managed-account):

```
$account = \Stripe\Account::create([
  "country" => "US",
  "managed" => true
]);
```

If your platform uses [standalone accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connecting-to-accounts#standalone-accounts), then you should ideally use the [OAuth flow](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts#oauth-flow) to let users log into their existing Stripe account or create a new account, and connect the account to your platform.

It is also possible to create standalone accounts via the API, with the [deferred account activation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/deferred-accounts#creating-a-standalone-account) feature:

```
$account = \Stripe\Account::create([
  "country" => "US",
  "managed" => false,
  "email" => "example@stripe.com"
]);
```

However, this will fail if the user already has a Stripe account registered with the email address you provide in the `email` parameter. In this case, you'd have to use the OAuth flow to connect their account to your platform.